# How to display attribute name instead of the field label on configuration attribute?

Tags: configuration, cpq

I have a Colour picklist field on Product Option object and it is used as an attribute across various products. But depending upon the product the attribute name can be Fabric Colour, Door Colour, Strap Colour etc. The issue is instead of the attribute name the field label is used as the display label during configuration. Is there anyway to avoid this?

This is how it is configured currently:

[image]

Configuration Page:

[image]

*Edit: Updated configuration page image

Comment: Formula field that concatenates picklist value + product name. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/formula_fields

Comment: @identigral, I didn't get how the comment is relevant to the question. I need a way to customize the label of the attribute on the configuration page, how will formula field help here?

Comment: Out of the box, the field label cannot be dynamic.  Based on the selected product, you want the product configuration to say _Fabric Colour_ instead of a generic _Colour_ in front of the pulldown menu . That's where the formula field comes in: it can support this. Another option is [dependent picklists](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/customize-a-salesforce-object/picklists-field-dependencies). Take a look at [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and have a think.